# Micrometer @Timed annotation write logs to file?

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

How to configure spring-boot Micrometer @Timed annotation to write logs into some log file instead of endpoint?

Comment: are you looking to write all metrics to logs or only those created via the @Timed annotation?

Comment: all metrics to logs

Answer (score 1):

To write all metrics to logs you can use the `LoggingMeterRegistry`. There is no autoconfiguration for this in spring boot so if you are using spring boot you will need to configure the required beans manually.

Source code: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/logging/LoggingMeterRegistry.java